# amsmath undefined control sequence

Tags: amsmath

I am using    `\documentclass{report}` and    `\usepackage{amsmath}`. My problem is relation symbols such as    `\backsim    \lesssim    \gnsim` are not working. Everytime I try to use such symbols error comes    `!Undefined control sequence.`
Please guide.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'll just turn this into an answer.

`amsmath` provides very few symbols, so in most cases [1] you need to load *both* `amsmath` and `amssymb`

[1] Some font packages provide the exact same set of symbols as `amssymb`, in which case you need to either not load `amssymb` at all, or make sure `amssymb` is loaded first, such that the font package and override the symbols with the ones suitable for this particular font. (the `kpfonts` package is an example of this).